# pandas in PyCharm: Unexpected type(s): (str) Possible type(s): (_SupportsIndex) (slice)

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, warnings, code-inspection

The following lines work and behave as expected, and don't produce an error. `history` is a pandas `df` that has a few columns including `date` and `close`

```
periods_data = [
        item[1] for item in history.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq=freq))
    ]
start_close = periods_data[start_period]['close'].mean()
```

However `['close']` is highlighted and has the warning in the title.

When I checked for the type returned by `df.groupby()`, I get `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

```
all([isinstance(item, pd.DataFrame) for item in periods_data])
Out[4]: True
```

Is there something I'm doing that I shouldn't?

Comment: pls, add some data so we can reproduce it, and also add the complete error log.

Comment: `The following lines work and behave as expected, and don't produce an error`. For data use [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and random values, the warning is not data specific.